# how to get jenkins build urls related to a jira fix version?

Tags: jenkins, jira

I need some help to ingrate Jenkins with jira my user case is this one : i would like to feed urls of builds related to a Jira fix version. This is important for us ( audit & compliance purposes )

How can i do that ?

Think you in advance.

regards,

Comment: Can you explain in more details what are you trying to achieve? or give an example ?

Comment: Hello, i weed when i use rest api of jira to retrieve a fix version, then i get a list of issues, from these issues i would retrieve a build commit of jenkins in goal to see that a jira fix version has been builded and tested on Jenkins automatically rather than going manually to jenkins to see evry build ( we use continous integration with automated tests )

Comment: I see. In our case we created a custom field in jira to store the jenkins build number and we run a python script as part of the jenkins build, that goes over the list of issues and sets this field. If this approach fits you i can provide more details in a formal answer.

Comment: @yossiz74 : yes, you can answer in a formal answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we handled it:

1. Add a custom text field to every jira issue type. it can be 'build number' or 'build url' or whatever information you need to display regarding the jenkins build
2. Create a python script that receives as parameters a list of jira issues and a build number.
   Using the JIRA python module (pip install jira), the script creates a connection to jira, goes over the list of issues and updates the custom field above to the given build number.
   if the list of issues is not known in advance, then instead of parameter you can provide (or hard-code) a JQL query which the script can use to obtain the list of issues.

   Depending on your needs, you may want to skip updating issues who already has a build 
   number set (either manually or by a previous build)

   (Sorry, i can't share exact code but it shouldn't be complicated.)
3. In your Jenkins build, add a 'batch command' item which runs that python script with the appropriate parameters.